# QGIS, metes and bounds, and elevation

Tags: qgis, elevation, metes-and-bounds

I'm using QGIS and the azimuth and distance plugin to create features from metes and bounds descriptions found in old deed and land grant records.  This is not forming closed polygons, I suspect due to elevation changes along the lines.  The resulting gap is in the neighborhood of 100ft, for a parcel in the range of 200 acres.  Is there a practical way to correct for, or estimate, this?

Comment: I had a civil engineering survey class as an undergrad in the 80's that practiced performing closure on a survey. Nowadays this is probably handled by a plugin. What have you tried?